# Picasso loads pictures to the wrong imageview in a list adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, picasso

I'm loading an image from a server to a list view item using picasso like this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View participantView;
    if(convertView == null) {
        participantView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.participant_item, parent, false);
    } else {
        participantView = convertView;
    }

    TextView textView = (TextView) participantView.findViewById(R.id.participantName);
    textView.setText(getItem(position).getName());
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) participantView.findViewById(R.id.participantImage);
    String profilePic = getItem(position).getProfilePic();

    if(!profilePic.equals("None")) {
        Log.d("tom.debug", "creating picture for user: " + getItem(position).getName());
        Picasso.with(this.context)
            .load(urlToProfilePics + profilePic)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.sample_0)
            .resize(52, 52)
            .into(imageView);
    } else {
        //load the place holder into the image view
        Picasso.with(this.context).load(R.drawable.sample_0);
    }

    if(!getItem(position).isHere()) {
        imageView.setColorFilter(Color.DKGRAY, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    }

    return participantView;
}
```

The debug log under the if statement only fires for users that really have a profile picture. (Users that don't have will get a value of `None`).

However, **some** of the other list view items (that don't have a profile pic) also get the picture loaded.

Another useful fact (I think): The items that get the bug changes when scrolling up and down the list.

I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: For googlers.. I've spent a lot of time on a similar bug but in a RecyclerView, only to realize that I accidentally called `myRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0)` after I updated the dataset but without implementing the necessary methods/classes that smoothScrollToPosition requires. Changing it to scrollToPosition(0) fixed my issues. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38391869/why-does-a-recyclerview-layoutmanagers-default-smoothscrolltoposition-method-lo

Answer (score 35):

Make sure you call the **cancelRequest** everytime you are about to use Picasso on a getView() from the Adapter..

```
// 1st: reset the imageView
Picasso.with(this.context).cancelRequest(holder.imageView); 

// 2nd start a new load for the imageView
Picasso.with(this.context).load(...).into(holder.imageView);
```

The reason is that the view you are reusing from the *convertView* parameter belongs to a previous row that was possibly already being loaded by Picasso for another picture.

*This is only really necessary when using the convertView, if you have just inflated a new layout, it won't be needed..but you can call always to make your code easier.*

Comment: ....I wasted a couple of hours (it's 1:25 AM at the moment) trying to wrestle with image finish loading and setting my cell background color to match my image theme color. . and, I notice it was setting the wrong cell. . .I have my sanity back now, thank you so much! :D

Comment: sorry, not worked for me, guess there is another problem for me, When I call for the picture of position 0, it will show the position 0, but there is no picture in position 1 , But the picture will also show the position 1 too, then again there is no picture in position 2, but the picture of position 0 is shown here also.  But if there is picture called for position 3,  it is shown in position 3, but there is no picture in position 4, but position 3's picture shown in position 4.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the following codes.First is my grid_row.xml file. It is grid items layout file

```
<ProgressBar
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/myprogress"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title"       />

<View
    android:layout_width="2dp"
    android:layout_height="2dp"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_height="165dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="125dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<View
    android:layout_width="2dp"
    android:layout_height="2dp"/>

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:ellipsize="marquee">
</TextView>

<View
    android:layout_width="2dp"
    android:layout_height="2dp"/>

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/subTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:ellipsize="marquee">
</TextView>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Then Please go ahead with the adapter class for reference.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.DisplayImageOptions;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoaderConfiguration;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist.FailReason;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist.ImageScaleType;
import    com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.display.FadeInBitmapDisplayer;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.listener.ImageLoadingListener;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.listener.ImageLoadingProgressListener;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.listener.SimpleImageLoadingListener;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by mpatil on 28/05/15.
 */
public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
private ArrayList<String> listTitle;
private ArrayList<String> listSubTitle;
private ArrayList<String> imgp;

private Context activity;
ViewHolder view;
Configuration_Parameter m_config=Configuration_Parameter.getInstance();

public GridViewAdapter(Context activity,ArrayList<String> listTitle, ArrayList<String> subTitle,ArrayList<String> img)
{
    super();
    this.listTitle = listTitle;
    this.imgp = img;
    this.listSubTitle=subTitle;
    this.activity = activity;


}

@Override
public int getCount()
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return listTitle.size();
}

@Override
public String getItem(int position)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return (String) (String) view.imgViewFlag.getTag();
}


@Override
public long getItemId(int position)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

public static class ViewHolder
{
    public ImageView imgViewFlag;
    public TextView txtViewTitle;
    public TextView txtViewSubTitle;
    public ProgressBar pg;

    public ViewHolder(View v)
    {

    }
    public ViewHolder()
    {
    }
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View participentView=convertView;

    if(participentView == null || participentView.getTag() == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = null;
        inflater=(LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = new ViewHolder();
        participentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_layout, null);
        view.txtViewTitle = (TextView) participentView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        view.txtViewSubTitle = (TextView) participentView.findViewById(R.id.subTitle);
        view.pg=(ProgressBar)participentView.findViewById(R.id.myprogress);
        view.imgViewFlag = (ImageView) participentView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);


        participentView.setTag(view);
    }
    else
    {
        view = (ViewHolder) participentView.getTag();
    }

        //download and display image from url

    view.txtViewTitle.setText(listTitle.get(position));
    view.txtViewSubTitle.setText(listSubTitle.get(position) + " subitem");
    ImageLoader imageLoader = null;
    imageLoader= ImageLoader.getInstance();

    DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.paceholder) // resource or drawable
            .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.error_page_logo) // resource or drawable
            .resetViewBeforeLoading(false)  // default
            .delayBeforeLoading(1000)
            .cacheInMemory(true) // default
            .cacheOnDisk(true) // default
        .build();


    m_config.imageLoader.displayImage(imgp.get(position), view.imgViewFlag,options,new SimpleImageLoadingListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View v)
        {
            Log.i("Inside onLoadingStarted " + position,"Yes");
            view.imgViewFlag.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            view.pg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            view.imgViewFlag.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        @Override
        public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View v, FailReason failReason)
        {
            Log.i("Inside onLoadingFailed " + position,"Yes");
            view.pg.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
        @Override
         public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View v, Bitmap    loadedImage)
        {
            Log.i("Ins onLoadingComplete " + position, "Yes");
            view.pg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            view.imgViewFlag.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            view.imgViewFlag.invalidate();
        }

    });



    return participentView;
 }

 }
```

I am sure that this will help definitely. Thanks NOSTRA for such a great library. Thumbs Up...!!! Happy Coding... :)

Answer (score 0):

In your getView() method change your Picasso code like this:

```
        try {
                Picasso.with(mActivity).
                        cancelRequest(holder.mImgCity);
                Picasso.with(mActivity).
                        load(getItem(position).getBackgroundImg()).
                        error(R.drawable.image_1).
                        into(holder.mImgCity);
            }
            catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                holder.mImgCity.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_1); //<-- Important line
            }
```

**Updated**

Use Viewholder concept in your getView() method. You will get your everything done with this only.

Answer (score -2):

I think I've been into the same situation. I suggest to use [ViewHolder](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder) pattern for your adapter.

It will be something like this.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolder holder;
    View participantView = convertView;
    if (participantView == null || participantView.getTag() == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            // don't forget to inflate the same layout
        participantView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.participant_item, null);
        holder = getHolder(participantView);
        assert participantView != null;
        participantView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) participantView.getTag();
    }

    holder.textView.setText(getItem(position).getName());
    String profilePic = getItem(position).getProfilePic();

    if(!profilePic.equals("None")) {
        Log.d("tom.debug", "creating picture for user: " + getItem(position).getName());
        Picasso.with(this.context)
        .load(urlToProfilePics + profilePic)
        .placeholder(R.drawable.sample_0)
        .resize(52, 52)
        .into(holder.imageView);
    } else {
        //load the place holder into the image view
        Picasso.with(this.context).load(R.drawable.sample_0);
    }

    if(!getItem(position).isHere()) {
        holder.imageView.setColorFilter(Color.DKGRAY, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    }

    resetViews(participantView);

    return participantView;
}

void resetViews(View v) {
    ViewHolder mHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
    mHolder.textView.invalidate();
    mHolder.imageView.invalidate();
}

static class ViewHolder { 
  TextView textView;
  ImageView imageView;
}
```

Comment: Looks like a good idea. but it didn't work. I might have implemented it slightly different than what you had in mind. in the resetViews there is a line `new ViewHolder(v)` but there is no such constructor in ViewHolder, what did you mean by that?

Comment: Also, about `resetViews(vi)`. what should `vi` be? I see no such object defined in your code...

Comment: @Tom yeah. it should be `participantView`