# How to load a bitmap into an image-view with Picasso

Tags: android, picasso, android-bitmap

**Yes, I am using Picasso to load a bitmap.** The reason is I am decoding URIs in one part of my adapter, and loading bitmaps in another, and I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26359608/picasso-loads-into-wrong-imageview-when-using-view-holder-pattern) that

> You should always call Picasso, even if your URL is null. This way it knows that the image view was recycled.

**So I tried this....**

```
Bitmap bitMap;

...

Picasso.with(getContext())
    .load(bitMap)
    .into(imageView);
```

**But I got this error**

> cannot resolve method 'load(android.graphics.Bitmap)'

Comment: why do you need `Picasso` it you have already the bitmap?

Comment: @Blackbelt You got that right.

Comment: You cant put `Bitmap` for `load` method you can use `uri` , `file` , `url path` and `int resource id`

Comment: How you creating `bitmap`??? if you creating `bitmap` by `uri` or `url` or by `file` put that resource in your `load` method as parameter

Comment: @the_prole this is not possible to u load bitmap. picasso its contain only string path , uri , file .

Comment: @Blackbelt Read my edit and tell me if it makes sense to you or not. Thanks.

Comment: @Trivial You may also read my edit.

Comment: it doesn't. If you have the `Uri` keep using it. Picasso caches the bitmaps for your internally, and, probably it uses the uri to look of the bitmap in the cache before downloading/loading it

Comment: if you need to load bitmaps asynchronously use Picasso. *and given that not all my files have valid URIs, I need to download the images, and I get the images as bitmaps*. If they don't have a valid uri/url how did you download them

Comment: @Blackbelt I did not download them. They are bitmaps which are by origin, encoded within the music files. Since not all these music files have bitmaps encoded within them, then I need to use a web service to query and download the image of the album art files. I'm am using Volley for this purpose, and the response in Volley is in the form of a Bitmap... so, on one hand I need Picasso, and on the other hand I have this bitmap...

Comment: @Clairvoyant I will check mark your answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Blackbelt - Hello, I read above discussion. I want to use Picasso just because of caching and async loading of images. Currently, In my project I got Byte array of from server. Then I convert byte array into Bitmap and then set it to my image View control.  So , now my question is that How can I use Picasso in my scenario ? As per above discussion, it seems that Picasso only work with URL not with other Byte[] OR Bitmap or other formats. Please help me to guide that how can I use Picasso if I have Byte[] or Bitmap ?

Comment: @AjaySharma did you try to give Picasso directly the url as input?

Comment: @Blackbelt I never try picasso , I just viewing the article and examples. It shows that we have to pass image url in Load method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant put Bitmap for load method of `Picasso`. You can use only `uri , file , url path and int resource id`.

If You are downloading image from **url** then you can do like as below code:

```
String url = "your_url";
Picasso.with(context).load(url)
    .placeholder(R.drawable.any_drawable)
    .error(R.drawable.anydrawable).into(your_imageView);
```

For other resource its same, only `load` method `parameter` would gets changed depending on the `resource` you are using.