# Why does a RecyclerView.LayoutManager's default smoothScrollToPosition method Log.e()?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm suprised by Android code sometimes. As the title asks;

Why does a `RecyclerView.LayoutManager's` default `smoothScrollToPosition` method write a `Log.e` message instead of throwing an exception?

(This is in the support v7 library, 24.0.0)

```
public void smoothScrollToPosition(RecyclerView recyclerView, State state, int position) {
        Log.e(TAG, "You must override smoothScrollToPosition to support smooth scrolling");
    }
```

I would expect this method to throw an exception since whoever called this method obviously didn't implement the required methods/classes.

Comment: Probably because it is not a core functionality of `RecyclerView.LayoutManager` and it's not worth crashing for

Comment: But I don't think anyone would accidentally call the method? Crashing early would expose the problem immediately, while in my case it was hiding a bug when replacing items in my recyclerView.

Comment: actually it should be an abstract method: that way you wouldn't be even able to run your code without implementing it in your custom `LayoutManager` class

Comment: @Anton. I kind of agree with you. It is indeed strange to call this method accidentally and it would be more logical to throw an exception if you want to have the method implemented or make it abstract as pskink suggests. However, I can also imagine that it is not considered a core feature and therefore not worth crashing for. I think it's just a matter of style